# In Grafana, is there way to retrieve the current URL?

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to get the browser's current URL, specifically the domain portion of the URL, into a Grafana variable.

i.e. If the user is viewing the Grafana dashboard through their browser at "https://localhost:3000/g/ABC123", I want to get either "https://localhost:3000" or "localhost:3000" into a variable.

I was hoping there would be a built-in variable that stores this, something like "window.location.hostname" in JavaScript, but I haven't been able to find anything.

**Edit:** For context, I'm trying to add a button using [the Button Panel plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudspout-button-panel/) that makes a POST request to another web server running on the same machine. The issue I'm having is the user can access the Grafana page from both the local browser and a remote browser. So setting the URL for the POST request to "https://localhost/..." won't work when the user is accessing the dashboard from a remote browser.

If I can get the hostname from the user's browser, then I can send the request to the correct URL regardless of where they're viewing it from.

Comment: AFAIK, **all** available variables are listed [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#global-variables). Since none of them have anything related to URL, I doubt you'll have luck with this idea.

Comment: One the other hand, I would strongly recommend setting-up Grafana and your additional service with the same domain for both internal and external use.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't sure if there were more variables documented elsewhere. Unfortunately I can't setup a permanent domain for this. I didn't mention in the question but it needs to be deployed to many devices, usually behind networks that are out of my control. I think I found a better way to do this using the HTML plugin instead though, so I'll post an answer if that works out.